# Retrofit cannot convert to xml to java.How to convert xml to java using retrofit2

Tags: retrofit2

Hi I am trying to use retrofit to write a simple rest client , I am trying to call a REST API GET that returns an xml response, however retrofit is not able to parse the xml.

Retrofit Code

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        // Create an instance of our OfferClient API interface.
        OfferClient offerClient = retrofit.create(OfferClient.class);

        // Create a call instance for looking up offers.
        String offerID="20000798";
        Call<Offer> call = offerClient.offers(offerID);
        Offer offer = call.execute().body();
        System.out.println("Offer Response..."+ offer.getDescription());
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'featureSetID'
>   does not have a match in class
>   com.intuit.schema.platform.webs.catalog.internal.offers.v3.Offer$Product
>   at line 1
>       at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:44)
>       at

Response that could not be un-marshalled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<offer xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/webs/catalog/internal/offers/v3">
    <offerID>20000798</offerID>
    <name>QBOA + QBO Plus + QBOP Enhanced CA CAD for Accountants</name>
    <description>QBOA + QBO Plus + QBOP Enhanced CA CAD for Accountants</description>
    <effectiveStartDate>2015-12-13T00:00:00-0800</effectiveStartDate>
    <currency>CAD</currency>
    <region>CA</region>
    <country>CA</country>
    <offerType>Free</offerType>
    <offerLevel>BASE</offerLevel>
    <customerSegment>ACCOUNTANT</customerSegment>
    <extendedCustomerSegment>REGULAR</extendedCustomerSegment>
    <salesChannel>DIRECT</salesChannel>
    <isListPriceOffer>true</isListPriceOffer>
    <product>
        <productID>22000220</productID>
        <packageId>21001070</packageId>
        <code>QBOA</code>
        <name>QuickBooks Online Accountant</name>
        <description>QuickBooks Online Accountant</description>
        <grantOfferingType>Intuit.smallbusiness.qba.web</grantOfferingType>
        <billingServiceType>/service/intuit/qboa</billingServiceType>
        <featureSet>
            <featureSetID>25001595</featureSetID>
            <code>QBOA_STANDARD</code>
            <name>QBO Accountant Standard</name>
            <status>Active</status>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Accountant Standard</description>
            <feature>
                <code>STANDARD</code>
                <name>Standard</name>
                <type>Feature Set</type>
            </feature>
        </featureSet>
        <charge>
            <chargeID>23001499</chargeID>
            <name>QuickBooks Online Accountant Standard</name>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Accountant Standard CA CAD Monthly Free</description>
            <type>Recurring</type>
        </charge>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productID>22000000</productID>
        <packageId>21001071</packageId>
        <code>QBO</code>
        <name>QuickBooks Online</name>
        <description>QuickBooks Online</description>
        <grantOfferingType>Intuit.sbe.salsa.default</grantOfferingType>
        <billingServiceType>/service/intuit/qbo</billingServiceType>
        <featureSet>
            <featureSetID>25000000</featureSetID>
            <code>QBO_PLUS</code>
            <name>QBO_PLUS</name>
            <status>Active</status>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Plus</description>
            <feature>
                <code>PLUS</code>
                <name>Plus</name>
                <type>Feature Set</type>
            </feature>
        </featureSet>
        <charge>
            <chargeID>23001500</chargeID>
            <name>QuickBooks Online Plus</name>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Plus Accountant CA CAD Monthly Free</description>
            <type>Recurring</type>
        </charge>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productID>22000154</productID>
        <dependentOnProductId>22000000</dependentOnProductId>
        <dependentOnProductCode>QBO</dependentOnProductCode>
        <packageId>21001323</packageId>
        <code>QBOP</code>
        <name>QuickBooks Online Payroll</name>
        <description>QuickBooks Online Payroll</description>
        <grantOfferingType>Intuit.ems.iop</grantOfferingType>
        <billingServiceType>/service/intuit/qbo/qbop</billingServiceType>
        <featureSet>
            <featureSetID>25000537</featureSetID>
            <code>ENHANCED</code>
            <name>ENHANCED</name>
            <status>Active</status>
            <description>ENHANCED</description>
            <feature>
                <code>ENHANCED</code>
                <name>Enhanced</name>
                <type>Feature Set</type>
            </feature>
        </featureSet>
        <charge>
            <chargeID>23001868</chargeID>
            <name>QuickBooks Online Payroll Enhanced</name>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Payroll Enhanced CA CAD Monthly Free</description>
            <type>Recurring</type>
        </charge>
        <charge>
            <chargeID>23001964</chargeID>
            <name>QuickBooks Online Payroll Enhanced Usage</name>
            <description>QuickBooks Online Payroll Enhanced Accountant CA CAD Usage Free</description>
            <type>Usage</type>
        </charge>
    </product>
    <transition>
        <transitionType>Resubscribe</transitionType>
        <fromOfferID>20000798</fromOfferID>
        <toOfferID>20000798</toOfferID>
    </transition>
</offer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()) with addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict()) in your retrofit builder. This will make the parser tolerant to xml tags which do not occur in your POJO

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: try to improve your post by clicking [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37256147/edit) link just below the post. Comment doesn't support code formatting features.